# TestCafe Studio: AssertionError: expected false to be truthy?

Tags: testing, automation, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

I'm a beginner TestCafe Studio user.
What on gods earth does this mean? My assertion is failing and can't figure out why.

AssertionError: expected false to be truthy

- expected - actual
  -false
  +undefined

Comment: You'd need to share the DOM and your actual TestCafe code if you really want a help here. No one can help you when there's not enough information in your question.

Answer (score 0):

There's an issue where '+true' should be shown instead of '+undefined': [Incorrect diff for the expect.contains assertion](https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/issues/5473)). It's almost fixed.

Pay attention to the message: 'expected false to be truthy'. This is a standard message that means that 'true' is unexpected and the expected value is 'false'.